# Novel about post-peak oil wind-powered renaissance

Tags: story-identification

This is particularly tough as I’m trying to identify a book recommended to me, rather than one I’ve read in the past.  I can’t contact the recommender, unfortunately.

The context was a discussion on twitter about alternative energy futures in science fiction.

The book in question was about a future civilization that rebounded (several hundred years?) after easily-accessible fossil fuels were exhausted. I believe the book explores a hypothetical advanced, industrial (?) civilization based on wind power rather than fossil fuels.

I had thought it was either by Poul Anderson or Jerry Pournelle, but after grabbing a copy of Anderson's "People of the Wind" which sounded likely, I think I may have been completely off. I don't believe it's a newer book - I would guess publication in the 1980s in the US.

I have had a bear of a time trying to find this through general internet search - real-life discussion of wind power is peppered with strings like "science fiction", "futuristic", etc.  Hoping the hive mind of stack exchange will more discerning.

Comment: How long ago was this?  Paolo Bacigalupi has written a bunch of post-oil stuff, but only since the early 2000s.

Comment: @Adam Wise - Can you provide a link to the Twitter discussion you mentioned?

Comment: I'm gonna downvote this one. You're basically describing an entire *genre* of books (e.g. steampunk) and we need more information.

Comment: Poul Anderson did write several works set in  such a future. I didn't like them so I didn't read many. I am away from reference materials, but there was a short story called something like 'Windmill' and a book called something like 'Marai and Kith'.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think this is certainly it, and that I am confusing "People of the Wind" and "The Sky People" by Poul Anderson.  If you care to, please make an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poul Anderson wrote several works set in such a future. This link from isfdb.org lists the series: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?276

As suggested in the comments, the specific work may be "The Sky People".

Comment: :) Maybe expand on that?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots unfortunately I've never read the book, just others in the series. I mentioned the series in a comment, and the OP must have researched it based on that, and found their book.